# How to make horizontal recyclerView with snapHelper and carousel effect?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, carousel

I need a horizontal recyclerView, which has central item with increased width and snap effect. Items in recyclerView are just a textView and I mustn't change textSize when change item width.

I have a horizontal recyclerView. I attached to it snapHelper from support library and I am increasing central item width in onScrolled method from OnScrollListener. Problem is when I scroll recyclerView to fast, when scroll is ended, recyclerView is flinging some time (1-2 seconds) before fully end scrolling. Maybe there is some library or solution or something else?

Comment: do you just need lib for proper snapping?

Comment: If you know some library which have functionality for snapping with carousel effect I would be glad to look at it